# Can't add Apple developer account VS mac 2017

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to add my Apple developer account to Visual studio.
In Preferences > "Apple Development Accounts" I click on the plus icon and Visual studio redirects me to fastlane.

I can add the account, and it asks for the permissions. I click on Always allow.
VS shows "Your session has expired" Please log in.

[Error message image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6OMD.png)

I can compile a project with the same package name in xcode, and it assigns a profile correctly and signs it.

I have installed Mac OS 10.12.5 Xcode 8.3.3 Visual Studio for Mac Version 7.0.1 (build 24) Fastlane updated today

I do not have much Mac experience, is there a log that I can check to identify the error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure fastlane is installed properly by going to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/provisioning/fastlane/

Once you have fastlane installed, open up a console and run "fastlane cert". You'll be prompted to sign into fastlane using your developer account credentials. After you're signed in, fastlane should add your cert to the keychain.

Go back into Apple Developer Accounts in VS Preferences and try adding your account again. This time you should not get the session timeout error.

Comment: @garie, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It appears that this is a [Xamarin bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58216) with two-factor authentication that will be resolved in version 7.2.